# 9 patch isn't working on device

Tags: android, eclipse, nine-patch

I'm trying to make a 9 patch image to be a header of my application but it doesn't work.

This is the image:

[image]

As you can already imagine, I want only the middle (blank) part to be streched and nothing else. It works normally in eclipse screen preview but it stretches it as if it wasn't 9 patch when i run it on my device.

I've had problems like this before so I'm clearly doing something wrong with 9 patches, I looked up a lot of info and tutorials on 9 patches and I just don't seem to get it. Could someone give me a good explanation where exactly to put the black dots for it to work and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you put those extra lines in an image, they work like this:

- Top and Left extra lines define the vertical and horizontal pixels which will be stretchable (the intersection is called stretchable area).
- Bottom and Right extra lines are optional and define the padding. In this case, the intersection is the region in which the content will be placed (the rest is the padding).

[image]

I recommend you to use the 9 Patch editor included with the Android sdk. It is called draw9patch and can be found at `<android-sdk-root>/tools`. You will be able to see a preview of your image with 9patch.

[image]

Links:

- [Draw 9-patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)
- [NinePatch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/NinePatch.html)
- [2D Graphics - Nine Patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I think I get it now, I'll use the editor to see if it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't believe it, the next thing I tried after asking a question worked. The fact that I had TWO lines in the bottom was the problem. I just put a single line BETWEEN the images in the bottom and it worked.

Like this:

[image]

If anyone still gives me a good explanation for each of the four sides of the image (why and where should the dots be put), I will still accept that answer.

Comment: are you using the 9 patch editor included with the android SDK?

Comment: No, I am doing it in photoshop